Flutter swift deprecated library confusion
This is what I get when I start debugging my Flutter project.
Launching lib/main.dart on macOS in debug mode...
macos/Runner/AppDelegate.swift uses the deprecated @NSApplicationMain attribute, updating.
Then it is not building at all.
The error I am getting is shown below

my current flutter versions are


What error are you encountering? Please show a minimal reproducible example

@RTXGamer, thanks for response, edited the post to show the error I am getting.
